# I want my post to republish again after adding a custom field

Tags: custom-field, loop, metabox, publish

I wanted a code in Wordpress that could allow me to republish the post every time I add a new custom field.
For example, if I already have a post and wanted to add an update to it; I want it to appear at the top of the site after updating it.

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't define that as default action. What happens if you actually only want fix a minor mistake, add/remove a word and the like? I'd either set the publishing time and date of the pasticular post _by hand_ or integrate a decent function into the Publish metabox, for instance a new button _Re-Post_ in addition to the standard _Update_ button, or a link _publish now_ and by clicking on it, you automaitcally set the current date and time for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by scheduling the post time to current time + a few seconds for example. Each time you add a custom field, just before saving - change the publish time to the current time and then save.

Comment: thanks this is not what I wanted exactly but I'll use it for now. Thanks again

Comment: each post started retrieving error 500 :s

Answer (score 0):

After a few research, i think

```
function set_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query )
{
    if ( is_admin() )
    {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin' );
```

could help you achieve what you want : the post in the administration will be ordered by modified time.

Comment: but will the original or older post stay ?

Comment: I want to order the posts in the index.php (or the loop) not in the dashboard

Comment: Then you use this filter in you wp query  : new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'modified', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query